# Trying to pass a value from VBA to sql stored proc, getting improperly defined error

Tags: sql, vba, stored-procedures

Just trying to pass a 5-letter string value (ie, "SSIID") from my VBA project to a parameter in my sql stored procedure but apparently I'm mixing up the types or something is going wrong. The error is:

> Parameter object is improperly defined.

I've looked up the comparable data types here http://www.w3schools.com/ado/ado_datatypes.asp and tried to match but to no avail. Any ideas?

**VBA**

```
.CreateParameter("@Location", adVarChar, adParamInput, , "SSIID")
```

**SQL Parameter**

```
@Location varchar
```

Comment: What's the size of your `varchar` parameter, and which version of SQL Server are you using?

Comment: Using Sql 2005 and the varchar size is 30

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[CreateParameter Method (ADO)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms677209%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

> **Remarks about Size parameter**
>
> If you specify a variable-length data type in the Type argument, you
>   must either pass a Size argument or set the Size property of the
>   Parameter object before appending it to the Parameters collection;
>   otherwise, an error occurs.

**e.g.**

```
.CreateParameter("@Location", adVarChar, adParamInput, 5, "SSIID")
```

Answer (score -1):

I was getting similar errors, and nothing seemed to work. It turned out that it was a datatype issue in SQL Server:  my stored proc had strings defined as NVARCHAR, and the strings sent by VBA from EXCEL were another datatype. Using strconv didn't help, so in the end I changed NVARCHAR to VARCHAR in the stored proc, and that solved it.

Mike Kenny